# Is it possible to copy files before and after some command execution from installer to user's machine in Advanced Installer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jenkins, advanced-installer

Is it possible to copy files from installer to user's machine before and after specific set of commands execution successful?

I have to execute XYZ command which needs some library files, so I want to copy these libraries from installer to user's machine. Once XYZ command runs successfully, other files and libraries required for project needs to be copied to user's Machine. Also I have integrated Advanced installer wih Jenkin plugin.
Is this possible with Advance Installer?
If yes then how can I specify files to be copied before XYZ command execution and files to be copied after command execution?
Also provide any reference guide for Integration of Jenkin plugin in Advanced installer?

Answer (score 1):

***Static Linking***: Are these a lot of files? Could you **statically link** them and put the executable in the binary table and call it as an EXE custom action? (or dll for that matter).

***Timing***: What is the executable doing? Could it conceivably be done after the setup is complete? Very often it can, even when you first think it can't. Just thinking out loud and trying to understand your scenario.

***Prerequisites***: I experimented a bit with the prerequisites view and getting that to kick off a binary doing stuff interactively, but I couldn't get a heartbeat in the time I had available. Suggest you go to the Advanced Installer community forums for more help: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/

Answer (score 0):

You can add your files *to be copied before command execution* in "Files and Folders" section of your setup project created in Advanced Installer.

Then you can create a BAT custom action as it is explained in their help article: [How to launch a CMD or BAT file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-launch-batch-file.html) ; the CMD custom action should be scheduled as deferred with no impersonation.

Finally you can create an additional setup project which will embed in "Files and Folders" section the *files to be copied after command execution*. The setup built by this additional project can be added as a post-install prerequisite in "Prerequisites" section of the former project.

And here you can find more details about [Advanced Installer integration with Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Advanced+Installer+Msi+Builder+Plugin)